# ANT jar issue. RT. jar not found in Java/lib

Tags: ant, path, java

I have a JDK installation which has the `\lib` folder and I can see `rt.jar` present in it. Still when I call ant, it gives me an error `Can't find rt.jar ...`.

I have got my basics right I think with `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` pointing to the correct directories.

Also `Path=JAVA_HOME/bin;ANT_HOME/bin;%Path%;`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by re-installing JDK and ANT. Not sure if this is really a solution, but I had ANT 1.8 and what looked like JDK 1.2.x (don't know how it existed on my system)

Answer (score 0):

Your path statement might work better like this:

`PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%ANT_HOME%/bin;%PATH%;`

Maybe it is finding a JRE in your path before the JDK

Comment: thanks but I had typed it by memory. It was already in the order you have mentioned.